# React JS three buttons need to call three diffrent apis calls

Tags: reactjs

have in 3 buttons, and when I have to click the button need to display 3 different API data needs to display in the console

Comment: In Functional Component

Comment: What have you tried? why do you think it's hard?

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused because of the three different data flows, here's an example of how this can be achieved.

```
const myBigComponent = () => {
  const callAPI1 = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(API1_URL);
    console.log(response.data);
  };
  const callAPI2 = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(API1_URL);
    console.log(response.data);
  };
  const callAPI3 = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(API1_URL);
    console.log(response.data);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={callAPI1}> Call API 1 </button>
      <button onClick={callAPI2}> Call API 2 </button>
      <button onClick={callAPI3}> Call API 3 </button>
    </>
  );
};
```